# I got a redirect_uri_mismatch error on django-allauth and github

Tags: django, github, oauth, django-allauth

I got the error message from Django's console. Why I got this error? I read and tried by [this tutorial](https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/).

```
"GET /accounts/github/login/callback?error=redirect_uri_mismatch&error_description=The+redirect_uri+MUST+match+the+registered+callback+URL+for+this+application.&error_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.github.com%2Fapps%2Fmanaging-oauth-apps%2Ftroubleshooting-authorization-request-errors%2F%23redirect-uri-mismatch&state=cpybsYqLpapp HTTP/1.1" 301 0
```

[Github app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Er9YL.png)

Comment: did you register your callback url in github develop?

Comment: I registered. "Authorization callback URL" is "http://127.0.0.1:9123/accounts/github/login/callback".

Comment: And you use `9123` port for runserver , and register it to github, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: That's wierd. You registered normally your `site` for `127.0.0.1:9123`? 
what if you change port to 8000?

Comment: I changed port 9123 to 8000. But I got a same error.

Answer (score 4):

try to change your redirect-url to:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/github/

use http and it will work. 
you can show the list of urls in your app by putting any wrong url value in the web browser to get all the list.
choose the one that much.
you can follow the steps in the link below:
https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/

**and put the link I provided in the github callback url.**

Comment: I followed the same tutorial (https://wsvincent.com/django-allauth-tutorial/) and had the same problem but, in my case, it worked with redirect url (Authorization callback URL) : http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/github/login/

Comment: I followed the same tutorial and got the same error. I think the Authorization Callback URL that I typed on Github had a typo. So I did what user11113594 recommended, I navigated through the list of URLs until I got the callback URL, copied and pasted on Github and it worked.